# Ouput data in a 1 dimensional array of string

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a 1 dimensional array string that has maybe the most 5 known items in it. I want to output each however many may be in the array string to a label on my form in the format like "I have a total of item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 in my array". Here's how my array looks like:

```
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles(C:\, "*.txt")

For each name in dirs
    mylabel.text = name >>> need each item to be here. Only ouputing last item.
next
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking, but is `mylabel.Text = "I have a total of " & String.Join(", ", dirs) & " in my array"` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mark yes, but the array is going to show the path as well in the dirs, i just need the name of the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to get just the file name from a full file path, and `String.Join` can turn the array into a comma separated string.  Combining both with the LINQ `Select` method would replace your `For Each` loop with:

```
mylabel.Text = "I have a total of " &
    String.Join(", ", dirs.Select(Function(x) Path.GetFileName(x))) &
    " in my array"
```

There is also [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) if you don't want the file extension in the output.